# Convert integer hashset to a integer array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, hashset

So i have made a hashset with -you've guessed it- integers in it. Now i need to convert this into a array, so i can refer to each array 'cell' and use the value from the hashset in a process.

Currently i add to the hashset like so:

```
 While NumbersToRemember.Count < 1
            RandomNumber = Random.Next(2, 6)
            If NumbersToRemember.Add(RandomNumber) then ...
```

i have tried using `NumbersToRemember.ToArray()` but it hasnt been working as expected.

Any advice?

Note: See comment by JerryM for the solution.

Comment: have you tried `.CopyTo()`?

Comment: You don't need to tell us you are using vb.net.  Most people can tell due to your tags and the syntax.  So I edited that out.

Comment: @Plutonix I have tried .CopyTo() however, when it comes to outputting the array i copied the hashset to it outputs only zeros.

Comment: You can refer to the members of a HashSet the same way as the members of an array. Example, `dim i as integer = NumbersToRember(0)`. Perhaps you don't need an array at all. But in any case, ToArray should work.

Comment: @JerryM I guess you can Jerry, I guess you can...Thanks.

Comment: Could you define "hasn't been working as expected"?

Comment: @Meta-Knight When i Went to retrieve values from the array it returned either zeros or repeated one number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not even a complete loop shown, so it is hard to tell what might be happening.  `it outputs only zeros` in comments indicates something else might be wrong.  Test:

```
Dim hs As New HashSet(Of Int32)
Dim temp As Int32

For n As Int32 = 1 To 10
    temp = rng.Next(2, 16)
    If hs.Contains(temp) = False Then
        hs.Add(temp)
    End If

Next

Dim nums = hs.ToArray
Console.WriteLine("Vals: {0}", String.Join(", ", hs.ToArray()))
Console.WriteLine("Nums: {0}", String.Join(", ", nums))
```

Output:

> Vals: 2, 7, 14, 11, 12, 10
>   Nums: 2, 7, 14, 11, 12, 10

It is hard to tell what you are trying to do, but to get a small set of random values in a given range, this seems a bit simpler:

```
Dim count As Int32 = 6
Dim randvals = Enumerable.Range(2, 16).
                OrderBy(Function(x) Rnd.Next()).
                Take(count).ToArray()
Console.WriteLine("Rand Vals: {0}", String.Join(", ", randvals))
```

> Rand Vals: 2, 13, 8, 6, 3, 12